# how to convert my result in table format

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying post my json result in table format how should achieve that.Igot result as [image: this is output I got]

I want it to display in table format .Here is my code

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text    replaced</div>

 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(function () 
 {
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'example.php',              
  data: "",                        

  dataType: 'json',                  
  success: function(data)        

        {   
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var uid = data[i].uid;             
  var firstname = data[i].firstname;       
  var lastname = data[i].lastname;
  var email = data[i].email;
  var username = data[i].username;
  var password = data[i].password;

  html += "<b>uid: </b>"+uid+"<b> firstname:   </b>"+firstname+"<b>  lastname: </b>"+lastname+"<b> email: </b>"+email+"<b> username: </b>"+username+"<b> password: </b>"+password; 
  }
$("#output").html( html );

  } 
  });
 }); 
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

the output is stored in var html what should I need to convert it into table format.

Comment: You have done everything just want someone who give finish to your work ?

Comment: not exactly. You little bit right but I'm new in php programming someone like you can help me to identify myself in this community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this part of code to format table instead just bold text:

```
...
var html = "<table>";
html += "<thead><tr><th>UID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th></tr></thead>";
html += "<tbody>";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    html += "<tr>";

    var uid = data[i].uid;             
    var firstname = data[i].firstname;       
    var lastname = data[i].lastname;
    var email = data[i].email;
    var username = data[i].username;
    var password = data[i].password;

    html += "<td>"+uid+"</td><td>"+firstname+"</td><td>"+lastname+"</td><td>"+email+"</td><td>"+username+"</td><td>"+password+"</td></tr>"; 
}
html +="</tbody></table>";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you mean.

Try:

```
var html = "<table>";
html += "<thead>";
html += "<tr>";
html += "<th>Uid</th>";
html += "<th>Firstname</th>";
html += "<th>Lastname</th>";
html += "<th>Email</th>";
html += "<th>Username</th>";
html += "<th>Password</th>";
html += "<tr>";
html += "</thead>";
html += "<tbody>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 var uid = data[i].uid;
 var firstname = data[i].firstname;
 var lastname = data[i].lastname;
 var email = data[i].email;
 var username = data[i].username;
 var password = data[i].password;
 html += "<tr>";
 html += "<td>" + uid + "</td>";
 html += "<td>" + firstname + "</td>";
 html += "<td>" + lastname + "</td>";
 html += "<td>" + email + "</td>";
 html += "<td>" + username + "</td>";
 html += "<td>" + password + "</td>";
 html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</tbody>";
$("#output").html(html);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It is nice to see that someone's help can pleas others and brings joy.thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can either directly create the Table within Javascript or within the PHP Script that returns the JSON Data however since you didn't show us your PHP Script, we'd go the Javascript Route like so:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function ()  {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url     : 'example.php',              
        data    : "",
        dataType: 'json',                  
        success : function(data) {   
            var html  = "<table class='data-tbl'>";
                html += "<tr class='data-head-row'>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>UID</th>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>First Name</th>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>Last Name</th>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>Email</th>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>Username</th>";
                html += "<th class='data-head-cell'>Password</th>";
                html += "</tr>";
                html += "<tbody class='data-content-body'>";
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var uid = data[i].uid;             
                var firstname  = data[i].firstname;       
                var lastname   = data[i].lastname;
                var email      = data[i].email;
                var username   = data[i].username;
                var password   = data[i].password;

                html    += "<tr class='data-content-row'>";
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + uid + "</td>"; 
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + firstname + "</td>";
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + lastname + "</td>";
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + email + "</td>";
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + username + "</td>";
                html    += "<td class='data-content-cell'>" + password + "</td>";
                html    += "</tr>";
            }
            html        += "</tbody>";
            html        += "</table>";
            $("#output").html( html );

         } 
     });
 }); 
 </script>
```